# How to setup a health check for a celery-sqs cluster on AWS

Tags: celery, amazon-sqs, amazon-elb

I'm trying to setup an ELB for my celery cluster that uses SQS as the broker. The instance is only running celery and not a webserver.

How can I go about setting up an ELB to health check the availability of the cluster. I've seen tutorials online suggesting a TCP check on 5672 for a celery cluster with rabbitmq, but since I'm using SQS here which works over HTTPS, I'm not quite sure how to go about with this?

Comment: Did you ever work out how to do this? I'm in the same boat. The docs https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html would conclude that monitoring is not available for SQS